# error run teleop_twist_keyboard package

Tags: teleop

[image: Rosanswers logo]

i install packge from

https://github.com/ros-teleop/teleop_twist_keyboard

and when i run this
rosrun teleop_twist_keyboard teleop_twist_keyboard.py
ihave this erorr

```
~$ rosrun teleop_twist_keyboard teleop_twist_keyboard.py
[rospack] Error: package 'teleop_twist_keyboard' not found
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/199363/error-run-teleop_twist_keyboard-package/) by [ksmksam](https://answers.ros.org/users/20913/ksmksam/) on ROS Answers with karma: 13 on 2014-12-12

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [AlexR](https://answers.ros.org/users/21013/alexr/) on 2014-12-12**:
please specify ROS distro you are using. Did you install the package inside your ros workspace and then sourced the setup.bash properly? Check again. you should run $ source ~/your_ros_worskpace/devel/setup.bash after you run the catkin_make command to source properly.

**Comment by [ksmksam](https://answers.ros.org/users/20913/ksmksam/) on 2014-12-12**:
indigo ros
and idont know how sourced the setup.bash

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I assume you followed the instructions for setting up your [ROS environment tutorial](http://wiki.ros.org/ROS/Tutorials/InstallingandConfiguringROSEnvironment).  You need to download the teleop_twist_keyboard from the github to your ~/catkin_ws/src folder.
Steps:

1. `cd ~/catkin_ws/src`
2. `git clone https://github.com/ros-teleop/teleop_twist_keyboard`
3. `cd ~/catkin_ws`
4. `catkin_make`
5. `source ~/catkin_ws/devel/setup.bash`
6. `source ~/.bashrc`

I also assume you have your ros environment in your bashrc file. It should contain the following lines :
source /opt/ros/indigo/setup.bash and you should add the following lines to your bashrc script by running :

`gedit ~/.bashrc` and add :

```
 source ~/catkin_ws/devel/setup.bash
```

New terminals will pick up when you open it. Also, you will need to remap linear and angular velocity for your robot to the /cmd_vel topic to use the keyboard for teleoperation. I would suggest looking into [turtlebot_teleop](https://github.com/turtlebot/turtlebot_apps/tree/indigo/turtlebot_teleop) package for details.

---

Originally posted by [AlexR](https://answers.ros.org/users/21013/alexr/) with karma: 654 on 2014-12-13

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) on 2014-12-13**:
I've removed the sudo for editing your bashrc. If you need sudo to edit your bashrc, the ownership or permissions are wrong, and you should fix them instead of editing your bashrc with sudo. Do: `sudo chown $USER:$USER ~/.bashrc` and `chmod 644 ~/.bashrc`

**Comment by [AlexR](https://answers.ros.org/users/21013/alexr/) on 2014-12-14**:
@ahendrix I did not knew that. I always use the sudo to edit my bashrc. Good suggestion though thanks.